# Setting up environment for development of Windows Phone 8 applications in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I recently got my Nokia Lumia 625 with Windows Phone 8 and now I want to start making apps for it. I am not fluent in C++, C# or .NET, only Web technologies like HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. I made a little research and found out that some clever people already made the web development for native apps possible. The problem here is that I use elementaryOS (Ubuntu based) Linux and all the tutorials show how to start application development with Visual Studio. If someone did it, please share the experience with me. I found that Cordova (previously PhoneGap) is probably the best tool out there, but I cannot set it up for Windows applications.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

To build locally cordova/phonegap apps for Windows Phone 8, you need the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

To install the Windows phone8 sdk, you need both Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8.

So with Ubuntu, you're kind of screwed.

You can have a look at phonegap build to build your app in Adobe's cloud. In that case you only need to provide either a git repository or a zip file to get an app.